# Audio DVR (DAR) software

Tags: audio, html5-audio, voip, web-audio-api, rtp

I have been looking for an open source live audio recording project for recording raw audio over IP. It seems I can only find a handful of video DVR projects, but no specific audio DAR projects. I have been told to take a look at the DVR projects and adapt them to audio only projects, but all of them I've found require some video component/stream. I have also looked as a few VOIP recording/logging projects, but those appear to be older non-updated projects that lack a lot of newer features like web based navigation.

I am looking for any ideas for live audio recording. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check Homer project at https://sipcapture.org/